# What Does "easy on the" Mean in Food Preparation?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage, food

If I walk into a restaurant and order a sandwich that comes with lettuce, and say "easy on the lettuce", would that mean that I wanted no lettuce at all, or simply less than normally comes with the sandwich?

I'm primarily referring to American usage, but would be curious about other locales as well.

Comment: FYI:  Note that, normally, you would only use "easy on" regarding, let's say, **"strong"** ingredients.  Easy on the chili!  Easy on the ketchup!  It sounds rather funny to say "easy on the lettuce" -- you'd perhaps go so far as to say that is "incorrect". It would almost sound like you were making a joke you know?

Comment: @JoeBlow Are you categorizing ketchup with strong ingredients? It sounds like you're making a joke.

Comment: Hi DC -- ketchup is a very strong food.  It's more or less as **strong as sugar**, which is the strongest food. http://divabetic.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/look-how-much-sugar-is-in-ketchup/  Anyway, it's a strange point to get hung up on.  Surely you would agree that "lettuce" is not in any way strong, it's not like say "hot sauce".  Typically you'd say "easy on...." regarding things you add, where indeed you may prefer to go "easy" on the "power".  Similarly, for example, you would not likely say "hit me!..." with the lettuce; you'd say "hit me!" with the whisky, hot sauce, etc. Cheers

Comment: Note too (as Frank raised) you would probably not say for example in a hamburger .. "go easy on the meat".  A hamburger "is" meat, so it doesn't sound right.  You say "go easy on..." the "accessories" (again, like the sauce, sugar, pickles, onions, etc). Similarly you couldn't really say "go easy on the bun", it would sound silly.  (You'd have to say, maybe, "use less bread" or "only one slice of bun" or "with the bun very thin please", of example.  "easy on the bun" doesn't work.)

Comment: Note that the expression is not limited to food. _Go easy on the gas_ = "Don't drive so fast."

Comment: @JoeBlow What I was getting at is that I would consider lettuce to be much more likely to offend an eater's taste preferences than ketchup. I can't remember the last person I ran into who had a problem with ketchup, but a sizable portion of the people I meet dislike lettuce. So, I'm not sure 'strongness' is really a reasonable measure here. Would you say "hit me with the ketchup"? I am absolutely certain that that would result in a room full of laughter anywhere that I have ever been.

Comment: Hi DC.  On the topic of "eating preferences", you and I would mutually think we "both know strange people".  heh!  I live in europe presently and in certain regions here people literally gag, vomit, when you mention "ketchup"!!  Conversely I find it incredible anyone would struggle to eat lettuce!  So that's by the by.  the fact is you DO use that phrase with "tomato sauce" but you do NOT use it with lettuce.  (if you don't believe me, ask others!)

Comment: regarding "hit me", I agree with you 100% that one would not usually saty "hit me with the ketchup".  that would be reserved for hot sauces, whisky etc.  the OP here is about "easy on the..."  Cheers!  and good eating!  :)

Comment: @200_success -- that's damned right.  Good point.

Comment: I say, "easy on the lettuce", all the time.  Particularly with tacos and subs where you can get buried under a mountain of shred. It makes less sense with leaf lettuce on a burger. I've never thought about it as being tied to "strong" or even necessarily to food.  To me it's an antonym to "hitting it hard".  As in "he's been hitting the bottle pretty hard".  You can use it in surgery and use, "easy on the pressure", to mean don't push to hard.  Relax and do it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would mean you wanted less than normally comes with the sandwich.

['go easy' definition from Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/go-easy)

I can't offer detailed evidence to support this, but I think it's quite a universal phrase. The link suggests it is common in British English and I know from experience it's also common here in Ireland.

Comment: You can also say this when they're in the process of adding the condiment and you think they're adding too much or might add too much (whether or not it's for you; it could be theirs, for that matter, although the condiments may or may not be yours, and you might want to preserve some; or you might suspect they're not aware of the amount). It's common in the USA, too. It seems they use this phrase in movies once in a while. It's sometimes about preventing them from adding too much, rather than always about ensuring less than normal (but it is about that too in some common contexts, of course).

Answer (score 2):

*Go easy on the X* means *Do not add too much X.*

Someone who likes mayonnaise but does not want a lot of it might say *Go easy on the mayo.*

Someone who likes a little bit of pepper, but not too much, might say *Go easy on the pepper.*

Answer (score -2):

I too believe that "easy on the..." means less. But I have now had several experiences, both in the US and abroad, where I said "go easy" and it was interpreted as "GIVE ME A BUNCH OF THAT." No clue how this misinterpretation comes about, but I recommend saying something like "a little bit of mayo."